# To find the number of zeros of function in given circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Find no of zeros of $z^7-4z^3+z+1=0$ which lie the interior of circle |z|=1. 
I know if $|f(z)-g(z)|\lt |f(z)|+|g(z)|$ then f and have same no of zeros . 
What should I choose f & g? Please help me to get no of zeros in that circle

Comment: Plot [$\text{arg } f(e^{it})$](http://urlz.fr/57ks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of artificial problem which is set as an exercise on Rouche's theorem. Typically on the circle in question (here $|z|=1$) one
term in the polynomial dominates the others (is larger than the rest combined). Can you tell which one of $z^7$, $-4z^3$, $z$ and $1$ that is?
Take that term to be $f(z)$ and the (negative of) the sum of the rest to be $g(z)$.

Comment: Is it $-4z^3$ which dominates the sum of others?

Comment: Can you prove that $|-4z^3|>|z^7+z+1|$ on the circle $|z|=1$?

Comment: Yes sure. Next I should find no of zeros f has. Right?

Comment: No of zeros are 3 right?

Comment: Indeed, $-4z^3$ has three zeros (counted with multiplicity) inside the unit circle, so the original polynomial also has three zeros there.

Comment: You made my day. Thanks for so simple and easy approach for my question from your side.